# Pasting charts from Excel with large files

Tags: excel, graph, powerpoint, copy-paste

I am having trouble when pasting some charts (not as a picture) from Excel into powerpoint. The problem is that the file is very large and a powerpoint which should be roughly, 200kb is around 20MB.

I was wondering if there was a way around this whereby you could paste it, but not as a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **Special Paste**, and paste as **Microsoft Graphic Object**

 (if you want to be able to edit it, i.e. change font, sizes, ...).

If you use the regular paste , it'll be *linked and with embedded data*, that is why it is so heavy!

Regretably, you canNOT change the default paste option in [powerpoint](/questions/tagged/powerpoint) like it possible in [ms-word](/questions/tagged/ms-word)...